# Can anyone explain why the name of a variable cannot begin with a full stop

Tags: python, variables

An explanation on why there is a syntax error when starting with a full stop while naming a variable

Comment: If you mean why you can't start variables with a `.`, it's because the [grammar doesn't allow it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the grammar doesn't allow it https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers .
And to give you a small example how it would mess things up imagine you had this code

```
class Fruit:
    name = 'Fruitas'

    @classmethod
    def printName(cls):
        print('The name is:', cls.name)

apple = Fruit()
apple.printName()
```

if you could use a `.` and named `.apple` when calling the fucntion how would python undertand it? You would need to call `.apple.printName()`. Python reads `.` as a connector...